# NextJS serves JSON as response and not html

Tags: node.js, next.js, response

I have built a blog site using NextJS. The blog has more content so it is not possible to use GetStaticProps and generate static pages during build time.

I have tried using GetServerSideProps and also GetStaticProps and GetStaticPath with fallback as blocking. In both the case, nextjs generates html for the first request and subsequent request, it is only calling _next/data and gets json response. I am more interested in getting html response every time as like in express-js or any other web framework. Is there any way in NextJS to get html content every time.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [],
        fallback: 'blocking',
      }
  }
```

Comment: Just don't use Next.Link, use regular anchor tags and then there will be no client side navigation. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks.. It worked. I got html response every time but the issue is in dev mode, It is throwing "Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server" error.

Comment: "Hydration failed" is a separate issue, it means you have different html generated on the server and on the first client side render. There are many questions open on SO about this error, just search for them and fix your issue accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you want to "disable" client side navigation just use regular anchor (`a`) elements instead of `Next.Link` components:

```
// Change this
<Link href="https://example.com" />
// To this
<a href="https://example.com" />
```

That way every navigation will be "full reload" navigation instead of in-build Next.js client side one.